# How to set printing orientation when using FlexPrintJob or PrintJob?

Tags: apache-flex, printing

I want to call the Flex printing API to set the print arguments before sending printing command.But there is no method in Flex(FlexPrintJob or PrintJob) to set the printing orientation.Are there some methods to solve this problem?My project is running in B/S structure and the view layer is in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Print orientation in flex is a read only property, since you cannot set the print orientation, but you can read. I think there is no way to achieve this solution.

Since it is not possible in Web Application but can achieve in AIR applications.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for the same in some other post of stack overview.

What you need to do is just create you own FlexPrintJob class replica of what existing FlexPrintJob class is and just

Add few line of Code is in addObject() function just add this line

```
PrintJob.orientation = "landscape".
```

You can make a setter getter for dynamic setting of Orienation value.

It is tested one so surely it should work.

Do let me know if you require any more details.